# Scaling Bone Joints in Envelope View

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

I have an armature whose envelope view shows some of the joints grotesquely out of whack so as to obscure the others, and I'm trying to visually scale the joints as per [a video](https://youtu.be/wBLv6oa60_k?t=121)'s illustration.

While entire bones will scale in edit or pose mode, the individual joints don't seem to scale visually in edit mode with the same data tab settings even in a new project:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens, if you change the value of the Radius in the properties panel? Does the 3D view change?

Comment: Yes, in a further-interesting way. It won't accept values below their current setting, yet it will let you drag the mouse to the left to reduce it as low as 0.010, by which the bulb shrinks accordingly.

Then, if you try scaling it or anything else on the armature, it and every joint you've manually adjusted in this way pops back to its original size (and radius value).

Comment: Since you have not gotten an answer yet, bump your thread by uploading your file to blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com.

Comment: [Here's the file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/d/2086/UnscalableEnvelopeJoints.blend). From a new project I just created a bone, subdivided with four divisions, selected "envelope" view from the Data tab, selected a joint. You can try scaling it.

Comment: Alt + S scaling works just fine. I can't recreate your problem with your file. Have you tried Setting Blender to factory after opening the file?

Comment: Ah, so it's **ALT**-S. That's good to know. Thanks, Leander.

Comment: Good to know your problem is resolved, I have added a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut to scale a bones radius is: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>